# Change theme of Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview 4

Tags: visual-studio, virtual-machine, visual-studio-2022, windows-11

I'm now having a window programming course,
which is learning how to develop a WinForms application using Visual Studio.
But I only have a m1 MacBook laptop,
so I download Visual Studio Preview on virtual machine.
But when I try to get familiar with how to use Visual Studio,
I found that I get trouble to change theme. This is my problem below:

1. **Download Visual Studio Theme Pack**
   [It mentions that it is most compatible with Visual Studio 2022 Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKf2x.png)
2. **Install .vsix file**
   [Use PowerShell in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khwew.png)
3. **Install failed**
   [Install log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1D90.png)

I guess that the reason is it only support normal Visual Studio 2022.
I'm using Visual Studio Preview, so it is incompatible. 
But it said that it can be compatible with Preview 4 and I cannot find any other way to install theme.

Visual Studio Info: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (ARM 64) - Preview
edition 17.4.0 Preview 4.0
Virtual machine: Parallels Desktop 18 for Mac Pro edition version 18.2.0
OS: Windows 11 arm64

Comment: Why is this so important? Note that the dark theme (black background, white font) is available by default.

Comment: @PMF Yeah you’re right. But everything happens for a reason, and I just want to know why this error occurred.

Comment: I was mainly asking because your question reads like this is blocking you from using VS. If you have problems with preview versions, it's probably best to create a ticket with Microsoft instead (you can click the feedback icon in the top right of the VS window)

Comment: @PMF Haha it looks like my words make you misunderstood, sorry for that. I still learning VS smoothly, and I’ll try to make a feedback. Thanks for your patience and your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Your theme just not support ARM64 arch.  Try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AustinStanding.vsthememidnightdeep

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.